# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and Glide 4.2 with the new android 3.0 no works

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-storage, android-recyclerview

In last days i update my android studio to 2.3 to 3.0 and then of that i have some problems with proyect and one of these is this:

I have one Holdermaps and Modelmaps class for retrieve the images from firebase, and one design_rowl_maps.layout how content of my images, and for last one activity_maps.xml this have the recyclerview what content all image that show to UI.

The problem is before update all is working ok, but after update the image dont charge more. I try to change somethings in the code with new code of the library of glide a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but dont work. So this is my code:

**Holder:**

```
public class MapsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;

public MapsHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

public void setPathName(String pathname) {
    TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_rowl_letters);
    post_title.setText(pathname);
}

public void setPathRoute(final Context ctx, final String pathrouth) {
    ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_rowl_letters);
    Glide.with(ctx).load(pathrouth).into(post_image);
    post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupDialog(ctx, pathrouth);
        }
    });
}

private void setupDialog(Context context, String path) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_image_full, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    ImageView img_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
    TextView lbl_close = view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_close);
    //Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_alert).into(img_photo);
    Glide.with(context).load(path).into(img_photo);
    lbl_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class MapsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;

public MapsHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

public void setPathName(String pathname) {
    TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_rowl_letters);
    post_title.setText(pathname);
}

public void setPathRoute(final Context ctx, final String pathrouth) {
    ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_rowl_letters);
    Glide.with(ctx).load(pathrouth).into(post_image);
    post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupDialog(ctx, pathrouth);
        }
    });
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Maps extends AppCompatActivity {

public Context ctx;
private DatabaseReference dbImages;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setupRecycler();
    //mAdapter.startListening();

}

private void setupRecycler() {

    dbImages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tblPathUploadsMaps");
    Query uploadMaps = dbImages.orderByKey();

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvMaps);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MapsModel> savedQuery =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MapsModel>().setQuery(uploadMaps, MapsModel.class).build();

    mAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MapsModel, MapsHolder>(savedQuery)
            {
                @Override
                public MapsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.design_rowl_maps, parent, false);
                    return new MapsHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(MapsHolder holder, int position, MapsModel model) {
                    holder.setPathName(model.getPathname());
                    holder.setPathRoute(ctx, model.getPathroute());
                }
            };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I do not what else to do, because i intent with all but i cant solve the problem. Thanks you for payme atention.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved of this way: `Glide.with(mView.getContext()).load(pathrouth).into(post_ima‌​ge);`